# ASP.net C# -- Merging a dataset that came from MySQL into a SQL Server 2008 table

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, merge, upsert

I load data from a **MySQL** database table into a `DataSet`.

Example:

```
MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(/*connection string*/);
MySqlCommand collectDataCommand = new MySqlCommand(/*Select comman*/, myConnection);

MySqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(collectDataCommand);
myConnection.Open();

DataSet tempData = new DataSet();
myDataAdapter.Fill(tempData);
```

Now that I have this info in a `DataSet`, I need to `MERGE` (or `UPSERT`) this info into a matching table in a **SQL Server 2008** database.

What would be the most efficient way of doing this? Is this even possible?

Many Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to do this is to use [Table-Valued Parameters (TVP)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx), supported by SQL Server 2008.

It is easy to implement both on the [SQL Server side](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489%28SQL.100%29.aspx) as well as the C# client side (the parameter will be of [SqlDbType.Structured](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype.aspx)). Basically, the steps are:

- Define a new "table type" in your database
- Add a parameter in your stored procedure, having the type that you just defined
- Add the corresponding parameter in your client C# code

Here's an extract from the relevant MSDN article:

"Table-valued parameters provide an easy way to marshal multiple rows of data from a client application to SQL Server without requiring multiple round trips or special server-side logic for processing the data. You can use table-valued parameters to encapsulate rows of data in a client application and send the data to the server in a single parameterized command. The incoming data rows are stored in a table variable that can then be operated on by using Transact-SQL.

"Column values in table-valued parameters can be accessed using standard Transact-SQL SELECT statements. Table-valued parameters are strongly typed and their structure is automatically validated. The size of table-valued parameters is limited only by server memory."